# Route ajax rails trouble

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have such jquery code:

```
  $(".quantity").blur(function() {
    console.log("upd");
    $.ajax({
    url: "/line_items/update_quantity/",
    type: "GET",
    data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), quantity: $(this).attr('quantity'), cart: $(this).attr('cart')} 
    });
  });
```

But this code generate me such url:

> .../line_items/update_quantity/?id=29&quantity=111&cart=27

But i need such url:

> .../line_items/update_quantity/id=28&quantity=2&cart=27

without ?

A have such routes:

> match 'line_items/:action/id=:id&quantity=:quantity&cart=:cart' =>
>   'line_items#update_quantity'

I tried, but nothing goes right. Help me please.

```
def update_quantity
    @cart = current_cart
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update_attribute(:quantity, params[:quantity]) #&& @cart.id == params[:cart]
        format.html { redirect_to(@line_item, :notice => 'Line item was successfully updated.') }
        format.js
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't create such routes. Apart from getting into petty issues like you already have, you are also making it impossible to alter the order in which parameters are defined.

Comment: first, update commands should be PUT/POST, not GET. that's not very secure. Second, you need to have a better understanding of the rails routing as rubish said: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @corroded you see answer of sailor, I need something like this, but! how to to this in post way, waht to change in method, added ^

Comment: I saw sailor's answer but it also isn't an elegant solution. you need to learn more about routing before doing more advanced stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters should be started after `?`

[HTTP/1.1: Protocol Parameters](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2)

> The "http" scheme is used to locate network resources via the HTTP protocol. This section defines the scheme-specific syntax and semantics for http URLs.
>
> http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]

your route can be replaced by

```
match 'line_items/:action/:id' => 'line_items#update_quantity'
```

`&quantity=:quantity&cart=:cart` is unnecessary

or better

```
resources :line_items do
  get :update_quantity, :on => :member
end
```

Comment: how then send this params to method? you didn't anderstand what i want

Comment: than it gives me such link update_quantity/28?quantity=2&cart=27 becouse if i done such as below jscript http://192.168.1.4:3000/line_items/update_quantity/?id=28&quantity=3&cart=27 it gives me Couldn't find LineItem with ID=update_quantity

Comment: show me please result of `rake routes | grep update_quantity`

Comment: /line_items/:action/id=:id&quantity=:quantity&cart=:cart(.:format) {:controller=>"line_items", :action=>"update_quantity"}

Comment: Use the first version of the route described by me

Comment: if i do in my way, and  /line_items/:action/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"line_items", :action=>"update_quantity"}
   if i do in your way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11160/discussion-between-ck3g-and-pavel)

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the id at the end of the routes manually:

```
$(".quantity").blur(function() {
    console.log("upd");
    $.ajax({
    url: "/line_items/update_quantity/" + $(this).attr("id"),
    type: "GET",
    data: {quantity: $(this).attr('quantity'), cart: $(this).attr('cart')} 
    });
  });
```

But i agree with rubish, you shouldn't update records with a GET url